# semiclassical proof of Wigner semicircle

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, cv.complex-variables

In Terence Tao's discussion of the [Gaussian Unitary Ensemble](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/the-dyson-and-airy-kernels-of-gue-via-semiclassical-analysis/), he derives the Dyson and Airy kernels.  The GUE is the probability distribution of the eigenvalues of a random Hermitian matrix.

\[  \int e^{-\mathrm{Tr} ; M^2}dM  \]

Ginibre calculated the density formula for the density of eigenvalues is symmetric in the variables:

\[ \rho(\vec{x}) = \prod_{i < j} \big|x_i - x_j\big|^2 e^{-\sum x_i^2}  = \det K_n(x_i, x_j) \]

Gaudin and Mehta calculated the kernel for this eigenvalue distribition to be a sum over Hermite polynomials:

\[ K_n(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \phi_k(x) \phi_k(y) = e^{-x^2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P_k(x) P_k(y)  \]

The functiosn $\phi_k$ are eigenfunctions of the Harmonic oscillator:

\[ H \; \phi = \left( -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \frac{x^2}{4}\right)\phi = E \; \phi \hspace{0.25in}\text{ so that }\hspace{0.25in} H\phi_k = \left(k + \frac{1}{2} \right)\phi_k\]

#### Semiclassical ( WKB ) approximation

Remark #1 in those notes indicate this is a [Schrodinger operator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84465/semiclassical-expansions-of-eigenvalues-of-schr%C3%B6dinger-operators) and a projection operator in phase space.

\[  H = p^2 + \frac{x^2}{4}  \leq n + \frac{1}{2}  \]

The energy levels correspond to [circles](https://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys603/kelly/Notes/Semiclassical.pdf) or ellipses.  We have $n$ fermions restricted to this region of phase space.  Rescale by the number of fermions and project to x-space: the semicircle distribution emerges.

You can already see this Fermi gas picture in Section 5 of the 1978 paper by [Brezin Parisi Itzykson and Zuber](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-59/issue-1/Planar-diagrams/cmp/1103901558.full).

---

The semiclassical approach can save space in certain discussions and it's use in statistical mechanics of harmonic oscillators ([e.g.](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0611062))

I would like to derive the semicircle law this way, although Tao's disclaimer scares me a little bit:

> For sake of completeness, I am recording some notes on this approach
> here, although to focus on the main ideas I will not be completely
> rigorous in the derivation (ignoring issues such as convegence of
> integrals or of operators, or (removable) singularities in kernels
> caused by zeroes in the denominator).

Where do the WKB approximation & the Fermi-Gas picture fail to be rigorous in this case? 
While, these discussions certainly have [gaps](http://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys580/semiclassical.pdf), perhaps no one will be the wiser.

Comment: The semicircle theorem itself is addressed in section 4 of Tao's notes http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/254a-notes-6-gaussian-ensembles/ He outlines careful approaches through **WKB approximation** and through **steepest descent**.